# How do you provide specific registrations in Autofac as parameters to other registrations?

Tags: autofac, autofac-module

Can you plase provide some guidance on how to pass some references to other registrations ?

```
//registration of 1st http client
    builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>()
      //.Keyed<HttpMessageInvoker>("authHttpClient")
     .WithProperties(new[] { new NamedPropertyParameter("PooledConnectionLifetime", 2 })
     .WithProperties(new[] { new NamedPropertyParameter("BaseAddress", "whatever"))})
     .SingleInstance();

//registration of 2nd httpclient
    builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>()
     .Keyed<HttpMessageInvoker>("dynamicsHttpClient")
     .WithProperties(new[] { new NamedPropertyParameter("PooledConnectionLifetime", 20) })
     .WithProperties(new[] { new NamedPropertyParameter("BaseAddress", "other something" })
    .SingleInstance();


// **I need to  do the registration of type and pass the 1st httpClient registration**
builder.RegisterType<DynamicsAuthApiGateway>()
    .As<IDynamicsAuthApiGateway>()

// **I need to do the registration of type pass 2nd instance of httpClient registration**
builder.RegisterType<DynamicsApiGateway>()
                .As<IDynamicsApiGateway>()
                .SingleInstance();

//Method ctor's
//DynamicsAuthApiGateway(**HttpClient client**, DynamicsAuthApiGatewaySettings apiGatewaySettings)
//DynamicsApiGateway(**HttpClient client**, Func<HttpResponseMessage, Task> errorHandler = null)
```

Can you help on how to achieve that ?

Any help would be appreciated ?

Thanks,
ME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with using keyed services. [Docs here for details and examples.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)

The easiest way will be to use the [`Autofac.Features.AttributeFilters.KeyFilterAttribute`](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html#keyfilterattribute) to just mark up the constructor on the consuming class.

First, update the consumers. Here's an example.

```cs
public class DynamicsAuthApiGateway : IDynamicsAuthApiGateway
{
  // KeyFilterAttribute on the parameter
  public DynamicsAuthApiGateway([KeyFilter("authHttpClient")] HttpClient client)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then register the keyed clients and enable the attribute filtering on the consumers.

```cs
// Don't forget
// using Autofac.Features.AttributeFilters;
// at the top... then:

// Register the HttpClient instances with keys
// and be sure the key is on the same type/interface
// as you see in the constructor of the consumer.
builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>()
       .Keyed<HttpClient>("authHttpClient")
       .SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>()
       .Keyed<HttpClient>("dynamicsHttpClient")
       .SingleInstance();

// Register the consumers and enable attribute filters
builder.RegisterType<DynamicsAuthApiGateway>()
       .As<IDynamicsAuthApiGateway>()
       .WithAttributeFiltering();
builder.RegisterType<DynamicsApiGateway>()
       .As<IDynamicsApiGateway>()
       .SingleInstance()
       .WithAttributeFiltering();
```

You have to opt into attribute filtering because it's extra perf overhead if you don't need it. If you don't put the `WithAttributeFiltering()` part, the filtering won't happen.

If you don't want that attribute in your class (e.g., you want to avoid tying Autofac into things) then it's a little harder - you'll need to use `ResolvedParameter` ([docs here](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html)).

That's going to look more like this (I'm kinda writing it off the top of my head, so if there's a typo or something, you've been warned, but it should be basically)...

```cs
// Register the HttpClient instances with keys
// and be sure the key is on the same type/interface
// as you see in the constructor of the consumer.
builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>()
       .Keyed<HttpClient>("authHttpClient")
       .SingleInstance();

// Register the consumers using resolved parameters.
builder.RegisterType<DynamicsAuthApiGateway>()
       .As<IDynamicsAuthApiGateway>()
       .WithParameter(
         new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(HttpClient),
           (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<HttpClient>("authHttpClient")));
```

It's not quite as clean but that keeps the Autofac references out of the consumers (if that matters). If you use that a lot, you could write your own extension method to make it easier. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Hi @Travis Illig,

Comment: Hi @Travis Illig, Thank you very much for your answer and by the options provided. They worked :) I opt by the usage of the second one, because just like you said to avoid adding extra Autofac dependencies on a class that ideally should not have that kind of things. Here is the final look of it

Comment: builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>()
.Keyed<HttpClient>("dynamicsHttpClient")
.WithParameters(new Parameter[]
{
 new ResolvedParameter(
   (param, ctx) => param.ParameterType == typeof(HttpMessageHandler) && param.Name == "handler", 
  (param, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<DynamicsAuthHandler>()),
 })
 .WithProperties(new[] { new NamedPropertyParameter("PooledConnectionLifetime", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)) }) //SocketsHttpHandler
.WithProperties(new[] { new NamedPropertyParameter("BaseAddress", new Uri(baseUri)) }).SingleInstance();